# How can i add custom field for Customer Manual order in order creation by admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, custom-options

I need to apply `shipping and handling` charges for customer in manual order, in normal checkout the shipping and handling cost received by default, in manual order for customer, how can i apply `custom field` for getting shipping and handling cost.

Comment: do you mean applying shipping and handling charges through custom code?

Comment: Yes, If i create manual order for customer, i need to enter shipping and handling cost, so that i need the field.